# Using ImportXML in Google Sheets to import sports data

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, xpath, google-sheets

Im trying to import the betting data from the following website:
https://www.pinnacle.com/en/odds/match/football/usa/nfl

Using the Inspect function in Chrome ive tried to identify the exact link to the data i require. The best i can do is the following:

```
=IMPORTXML(A5,"//td[@class='game-name name']/span")
```

This gives me a number of variable names but no data.

Ideally i'd like to import the table odds-data with all the relevant columns.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The value tables are loaded in separately with Javascript *after* the base page has loaded. `IMPORTXML` is not a browser, it does not execute any scripts. Disable Javascript to see what `IMPORTXML` is seeing. See if they offer an API instead of trying to scrape their website.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I disable Javascript the table doesnt appear so thats why im not getting any data. Is there any other way of importing the table? Ive seen some answers use scripts but i dont seem to be having any success with them.

Answer (score 1):

To get the values that are used to build the data table inspect the network tab in the (Chrome) Developer tools carefully and you will find a call [889?callback=angular.callbacks._0](https://www.pinnacle.com/webapi/1.17/api/v1/GuestLines/Deadball/15/889?callback=angular.callbacks._0) that contains the values as a JSON object wrapped by angular function.

```
angular.callbacks._0({"ResponseTime":"2018-09-09T20:19:26Z","OddsType":"american","Leagues":[{"LeagueId":889,"SportId":15,"IsLive":false,"HasLiveLines":true,"Events":[{"EventId":841876318,"LeagueId":889,"SaveTime":"2018-09-10T03:15:47Z","DateAndTime":"2018-09-10T16:10:00Z","Cutoff":"2018-09-10T23:10:00Z","HoursAndMinutes":"16.10","PeriodNumber":0,"IsLive":false,"IsOffline":false,"LiveStatus":2,"Totals":{"OverPrice":104.0,"UnderPrice":-115.0,"Min":45.0},"IsHandicapEmpty":false,"IsMoneyLineEmpty":false,"IsTeamTotalsEmpty":false,"Participants":[{"Id":479,"Name":"New York Jets","Type":"Team1","Handicap":{"Price":-113.0,"Min":7.0},"MoneyLine":256.0,"TeamTotals":{"OverPrice":-110.0,"UnderPrice":-106.0,"Min":17.5},"IsDraw":false},{"Id":480,"Name":"Detroit Lions","Type":"T...
```

There are several options to get this into Google spreadsheet. The most straightforward, but not necessarily the easiest option is to use the Script Editor to retrieve the response string, extract the JSON string, and then retrieve the data in question from the JSON object. Here is a snippet to get you started:

```
function getJSON(aUrl,sheetname) {
  var aUrl = "https://www.pinnacle.com/webapi/1.17/api/v1/GuestLines/Deadball/15/889?callback=angular.callbacks._0";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(aUrl);
  var jsonString = response.getContentText().replace("angular.callbacks._0(", "").replace(");", "");
  Logger.log(jsonString);
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(jsonString); //
  var data = dataAll.Leagues["0"].Events;
  /*for (i in data){
    var overPrice = data[i].Totals.OverPrice;
    var underPrice = data[i].Totals.UnderPrice;
    var minPrice = data[i].Totals.Min;
    //
  }*/

  //funcs() to insert data into spreadsheet
}
```

First, you need to identify the stuff you want to get from the object; I suspect the data you are looking for can be found under `dataAll.Leagues["0"].Events`.

The next step would insert the data from the object int spreadsheet cells. Here's a [sample](https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/1442370) how to do that.